# Find a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

Is is possible to find a metric $d$ on $\mathbb{R}$ so that $(\mathbb{R}, d)$ would have a **finite** number of open sets?

Comment: In a metric space, what do you know about the singleton sets, $\{x\}$?

Comment: I guess that in $\mathbb{R}$, every singleton is open and closed.

Comment: Generally, not open. But closed, in every metric space, singletons are closed. How many singletons are there in $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: An uncountable infinity.

Comment: Right. And how many distinct open sets can you obtain with a simple operation from these closed sets?

Comment: What do you mean by a "simple operation"? I don't understand your question. Do you mean reunion, intersection or what?

Comment: Not one of these. Something along the lines "$A$ is closed if and only if $__$ is open".

Comment: A is closed in X if and only if X\A is open. Am I right? I guess there will always be  an uncountable infinity of open sets in  $\mathbb{R}$

Comment: Right, I meant taking the complement. And in any metric space $(X,d)$, there are at least $\operatorname{card} X$ open sets by this argument. Taking $X = \mathbb{R}$, we have exactly $\operatorname{card} \mathbb{R}$ open sets when we use the standard metric, and we have $2^{\operatorname{card} \mathbb{R}}$ open sets if we use the discrete metric.

Comment: I see that, but there will be an uncountable infinity of open sets in  $(\mathbb{R},d)$ for any metric d?

Comment: Yes, there are always uncountably many. But we can't know the exact cardinality of the family of open sets unless we know which metric.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If $(X,d)$ is a metric space and $X$ is not finite then choose $n$ arbitrary elements $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ of $X$ and let 
$$d_0:=\frac{1}{3}\min\{d(x_i,x_j)|i \ne j\}$$ 
We have $d_0>0$ and the sets $$B(x_i,d_0)=\{x\in X|d(x_i,x)<d_0\}$$ are open and disjoint and therefore different.

Answer (score -1):

I cannot write English very well ,but I do my best from Japan.

The metric $d$ is defined by
$d(x,y)=\left\{ \begin{matrix}  1 & (x \not= y ) \\
0 & (x=y)\end{matrix} \right. $ ,we call it discrete metric.
The metric $d$ yields discrete topology.
So, there will be open finite sets.

Let me know,I make mistakes this sentence.

Comment: This is not correct, as there are uncountable many finite subsets of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: @Taku: He wants the *number* of open sets to be finite (which is impossible), not to have a finite open subset.